# генератор списков

Tags: python, list, compression

подскажите как можно записать это с помощью генератора списков

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
a = []
x = 0
for i in range(n):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        a[i].append(j+x)
    x += m
print(a)
```

Comment: Навскидку `a = [[j+i*m for j in range(m)] for i in range(n)]`.

Comment: Извините за доп. вопрос: _записать это_ - вы знаете как **это** называется?

Answer (score 3):

Все ваши [предыдущие вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/355381/stanislav-repin?tab=questions), включая данный, связаны с матрицами. Возможно вам стоит ознакомиться с модулем [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html), предназначенным для быстрой и эффективной обработки матричных данных:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(n * m).reshape(n, m)
print(a)
print(f"shape: {a.shape}")
```

---

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]

shape: (4, 5)
```

---

Приведение 2D Numpy матрицы к списку списков:

```
print(a.tolist())
```

---

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```